# python + No module named cryptography.fernet after upgrade cryptography pkg

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pip, rhel

we update some python pkgs and modules

one of them was the pkg  `cryptography`

we update the  cryptography  from version `cryptography (1.7.1)` to `cryptography (2.9.2)`

but when we access the python shell , we get `ImportError: No module named cryptography.fernet`

in spite cryptography is installed

```
pip list |grep  cryptography
cryptography (2.9.2)
```

from python shell

```
python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Sep 12 2018, 05:31:16)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named cryptography.fernet
```

Note - on the previous version `cryptography (1.7.1)` , every thing was ok

so what could be the problem with the module?

note the same problem is from the python script

```
import sys
import os
import base64
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

installing of the following rpm file solved the problem

```
yum localinstall python2-cryptography-1.7.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
Loaded plugins: langpacks
Configuration
Examining python2-cryptography-1.7.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm: python2-cryptography-1.7.2-2.el7.x86_64
Marking python2-cryptography-1.7.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package python2-cryptography.x86_64 0:1.7.2-2.el7 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

=============================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                       Arch                            Version                               Repository                                                         Size
=============================================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 python2-cryptography                          x86_64                          1.7.2-2.el7                           /python2-cryptography-1.7.2-2.el7.x86_64                          2.6 M

Transaction Summary
=============================================================================================================================================================================================
Install  1 Package

Total size: 2.6 M
Installed size: 2.6 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]: n
Exiting on user command
Your transaction was saved, rerun it with:
 yum load-transaction /tmp/yum_save_tx.2020-06-04.09-55.SDc8o9.yumtx
[root@master02 TEST1]# yum localinstall python2-cryptography-1.7.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
Loaded plugins: langpacks
Repository HDP-2.6-repo-1 is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.22-repo-1 is listed more than once in the configuration
Examining python2-cryptography-1.7.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm: python2-cryptography-1.7.2-2.el7.x86_64
Marking python2-cryptography-1.7.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package python2-cryptography.x86_64 0:1.7.2-2.el7 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

=============================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                       Arch                            Version                               Repository                                                         Size
=============================================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 python2-cryptography                          x86_64                          1.7.2-2.el7                           /python2-cryptography-1.7.2-2.el7.x86_64                          2.6 M

Transaction Summary
=============================================================================================================================================================================================
Install  1 Package

Total size: 2.6 M
Installed size: 2.6 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
Downloading packages:
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
  Installing : python2-cryptography-1.7.2-2.el7.x86_64                                                                                                                                   1/1
  Verifying  : python2-cryptography-1.7.2-2.el7.x86_64                                                                                                                                   1/1

Installed:
  python2-cryptography.x86_64 0:1.7.2-2.el7

Complete!
```